# Erro no APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01 - ORACLE APEX

Tags: api, oracle, pl-sql, apex

Estou com um problema com esse esse script abaixo:

tenho um checkbox na minha página ( não em relatório, na página mesmo, um item de página) e gostaria que o mesmo ao ser clicado e pressionado um botão submit realizasse o procedimento do script, porém ele faz o processo mas não me retorna nada. acredito que o problema seja no LOOP do APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01 . Alguém consegue me ajudar com isso?

```
DECLARE
    V_DS_COLAB VARCHAR2(50);

BEGIN
    APEX_DEBUG.MESSAGE('CHECK:'|| vCHECK);
    FOR A IN 1 .. APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.COUNT LOOP
        BEGIN
            SELECT C.DS_COLABORADOR INTO V_DS_COLAB FROM COLABORADOR C WHERE C.USER_APEX = V('APP_USER') ;          
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN

  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'NENHUM REGISTRO ENCONTRADO!');

  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002,'MAIS QUE UM REGISTRO ENCONTRADO!'); 

  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20003,'ERRO NAO PREVISTO' || SQLERRM) ;

    END;

        :P12_SUPER := (V_DS_COLAB || ' - ' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI'));
        UPDATE COMPETENCIA_COLABORADOR CC SET FINALIZADO_SN = 'S'
            WHERE CC.CD_EQUIPE = :P12_EQUIPE 
              AND CC.CD_COMPETENCIA = (SELECT C.CD_COMPETENCIA 
                                           FROM COMPETENCIA C 
                                               WHERE TO_DATE(LPAD(C.MES_COMPETENCIA,2,'0') || '/' || C.ANO_COMPETENCIA,'MM/RRRR') = TO_DATE(:P12_COMPETENCIA,'MM/RRRR'));

END LOOP;
```

END;

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que entendi os CheckBoxes serão preenchidos no caso do colaborador ser o usuário da aplicação. Teste esse código em `textfield`, por exemplo. Você deve simular essas situações em outros contextos, por exemplo fazendo um `insert` em uma tabela de teste para ver se pelo menos o código está sendo executado, e apenas não renderizado em tela.

Aqui um trecho do livro do **Expert Oracle Application, 2nd Ed.** sobre *CheckBoxes*:

> The Checkbox item was different from the other items in
>   APEX—its value was not submitted to the server for the empty state. This means that the array g_f01 would
>   contain the values for checked items only; there was no really good way to get around this problem.
>   APEX 4 changed this for the better by introducing the Single Checkbox item. This item can be used